# What does 酿 mean in 苹果iPhone 5酿致命意外?

Tags: meaning

Taken from [this news article](http://www.singtao.com/yesterday/loc/0714ao14.html)

What does "酿" mean in this sentence:

> 苹果iPhone 5酿致命意外

Comment: Also, please take the news article with a grain of salt. This story has not been verified to be true.

Comment: @Stan Your comment is as complete as an answer so you should make it be:)

Comment: @NS.X. I thought my statement of "the causality" sounded a little personal so I didn't put it as an answer :) Anyway, I will follow your advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[酿](http://www.zdic.net/z/26/js/917F.htm) means **lead to/result in** in that sentence.

As the original meaning of 酿 is "the process of making wine", the sentence

> A + 酿(成) + B

is a metaphor for "***A leads to B*** (in a gradual/long-term process)", `喻事情积渐而成`.

---

#### Issue of the causality

Personally, I think the sentence

> 苹果 iPhone 5 酿致命意外。 Apple iPhone 5 leads to a fatal accident.

is not rigorous enough. Though it is acceptable, and one may complete the sentence in mind as

> 苹果 iPhone 5 (的设计缺陷) 酿致命意外。 (The design flaw of) Apple iPhone 5 leads to a fatal accident.

So, a more logical sample sentence would be

> 疏忽酿大错。 Carelessness leads to serious blunders.

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me if this is ever used conversationally?

Comment: @xiaohouzi79 Yes, it can be used in a conversation. `酿` is a literary word, but not literary enough to sound like a pedant in a conversation :)

Comment: @Stan I don't think we use 酿 as this meaning too much in daily conversations. Instead, it appears more in written Chinese. In oral Chinese, the collocation of "酿酒" in which 酿 means "brew" or the collocation of "佳酿" which means vintage wine is more common.

Comment: @52Dora: There's no conflict. I hadn't meant *it can be used too much in conversations*, but *it's acceptable in conversations*.